# RCP application for Mac - Carbon or Cocoa?

Tags: java, macos, swt, rcp

First of all, I am not Mac developer and a very casual Mac user, so please bear with my question.

I've got a fairly large RCP application which is targeted mainly for windows and linux, works well on both. Now, having tried to run it on OSX (carbon x86) I've found it looks pretty ugly, nothing at all like Mac and quite clumsy to use. For example, here is a simplest thing I can't make even look straight, no matter what I do those buttons just wouldn't sit the way I want them to be: [image: mac] And this is how it looks on windows for comparison (same code base): [image: win].

It cuts the buttons height, doesn't place them right, alignment is a mess, etc.

And these are just tips of an iceberg, there are probably bigger issues out there.

So, I've got two questions:

1) Should I bother at all fighting for the presence on MAC with RCP application? May be it's a dead end and nobody actually does it? After all apple and java don't mix much.

2) If I go for it, should I be targeting carbon or cocoa? I will want to look forward, for newest mac developments. I would centrality prefer only one of them, which one would you pick? What's the criteria?

---

**UPDATE:**

I've created the distribution for cocoa and all these strange rendering problems disappeared. Using eclispe rcp 3.7. Everything looks perfect.

Comment: @awoodland who closed the question - I have actually received a very valuable answer with great references and practical expertise. Would probably have received even more if you weren't interfered. IMHO - over moderated. I don't think it's nice to shut down the subject after you have actually seen the valuable answers are coming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This is sort of a subjective question.  Do other people do it?  Sure, with varying degrees of investment and caring.  Should you do it?  I'd say it depends on what your users want and expect.
2. Use Cocoa.  [Carbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_%28API%29) is the old Mac OS 9 compatible API, while [Cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) is the new Mac OS X API (formerly the NextStep API.)  Historically, Eclipse (and thus SWT and RCP applications) only supported Carbon, however Cocoa support was added in Eclipse 3.4.  (The Cocoa event loop and the SWT event loop proved hard to integrate, however Apple invited the SWT team to Cupertino to sit down and make it work.)

   That said, I'd be surprised if your app looked very different between the two platforms.  There are definitely some minor UI differences around some widgets - the focus ring in particular looks slightly different - but on the whole you should realistically be able to test in either Carbon or Cocoa.  But as a release vehicle, I'd use Cocoa.

Working as the "Mac guy" on an Eclipse plug-in (and previously an RCP application), I can provide a few pointers if you decide to invest some time in improving the Mac OS experience:

1. It's probably worth reading the Mac [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html).  Realistically, nobody (including Apple) takes this document as unbreakable law, but it is a good start to thinking about a Mac app as a *Mac app*.  I doubt the HIG says this, but having icons on buttons is just not a particularly Mac-ish thing to do.  (It would more likely be in the toolbar.)
2. Eclipse bugzilla is your friend.  When you find yourself beating your head against the desk wondering why `Button` with the `SWT.ARROW` bit doesn't look right on Carbon, it's good to know that there might be a workaround in the bug comments.  Plus, you sometimes get people posting fixes that you can integrate (since as an RCP application, you can ship your own SWT version.)  For example, the ability to [use the proper window toolbar](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=222859) in Mac OS appeared in bugzilla first.
3. Mac OS apps tend to use more whitespace than Windows or GTK apps do.  If you're only developing for Windows and Linux, there's a tendency to just eyeball a number of pixels for padding and margins in layouts.  When you run this application on Mac OS it tends to look strange and scrunched up.  It's best to set margins and padding based on the system recommendations.  You can use `IDialogConstants` to get these defaults (in DLUs) and then convert to pixels.  For example:

   ```
   int marginW = Dialog.convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(fontMetrics, IDialogConstants.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN);
   int marginH = Dialog.convertVerticalDLUsToPixels(fontMetrics, IDialogConstants.VERTICAL_MARGIN);

   int hSpacing = Dialog.convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(fontMetrics, IDialogConstants.HORIZONTAL_SPACING);
   int vSpacing = Dialog.convertVerticalDLUsToPixels(fontMetrics, IDialogConstants.VERTICAL_SPACING);
   ```

   You may wish to use a Dialog and Composite base class to provide this for you so that you have simple accessors for this.
4. Recall that OK and Cancel buttons on Windows are backwards from Mac OS and GTK.  The `Dialog` class handles putting the default (OK, Yes, Accept, etc) button in the correct place for you.  If you start putting strange buttons in your dialog button bar, it's important to be aware that SWT may reorder them for you.
5. Don't assume the Control key when hooking up key listeners or accelerators.  Apple users probably expect to use the Command key (aka the Apple key) in that situation.  For accelerators, just use `M1` instead of `CTRL`.
6. When you release, repackage your application into the `.app`.  Mac users expect a single `.app` with the resources inside it, they don't expect a folder with a `.app` and a bunch of other unnecessary folders.   The output from PDE build for the Mac looks just like every other platform - a folder with the launcher inside, next to your `plugins` and `features` directories.  As a post-build step, you can move the `plugins` and `features` directories inside the `.app` directory and edit the launcher to reflect the changes.  (There's a perl script floating around the internet, I think, if not I can post one.)